# Center certain elements vertically in a Row widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following Widget tree of a ListView item:

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Align(
        child: Assets.images.select.image(height: 20, width: 20),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 4,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
            child: Text(
              food.name,
              style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  fontSize: FontSize.medium.size,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
            child: Text(
              "100 g",
              style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                  color: Color(0xFF777777),
                  fontSize: FontSize.small.size,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Text(
              "${food.carbohydratesPerGram} g / HC",
              style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  fontSize: FontSize.medium.size,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

But it turns out like this:
[image: result image]

I tried putting the ball in a column with "mainAxisAlignment" set to "mainAxisAlignment.center"

How can I get the ball on the left vertically centered in the row?

Comment: Did you try using ListTile widget?

Comment: No. I don't think I can do this type of layout with ListTile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it somewhat working: instead of using an `image` widget, I used an `IconButton` widget and it magically worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use crossAxisAlignment.

When you are in a row element the main is horizontal axis and the cross is vertical axis

When you are ina  column the main is verticla axis and the cross is horizontal axis.

So in your Row element to center element in vertical axis you need to use

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
```

Comment: That put all elements centered in the row.

Answer (score -1):

Add `alignment: Alignment.center` to you `Assets.images`.

```
Expanded(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center, // This Here
    child: Assets.images.select.image(height: 20, width: 20),
  ),
),
```

And I think your row is taking the height of your whole screen. If that is the case your image will come to the center of the screen coz your row is on the whole screen make sure that is not the case.

Comment: The screenshot is from a ListView